# How to get usb ids with awk or sed by a generic search string?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

what I want is a generic search that allows searching for a string. The command should return the usb ids that I can reuse to automatically generate my udev android.rules file for adb.

Is there a way to do this using sed? I have no idea how to use sed and it's pretty hard to find tutorials on it. My Google Fu is not the best :(

What I've tried without any success so far:

```
 lsusb | grep ZTE | sed -r 's/ID ([0-9abcdef]{4})\:([0-9abcdef]{4})\:/\1/g'
```

It gives you an idea what I want to try, but it's not working anyhow.

Comment: If I understand your question, you're reall very close to an answer. But not all of us have access to `lsusb` (or have anything connected). Can you 1. Add 1-2 lines of sample output from `lsusb` AND 2. then indicate what the output should be, give that sample input. As you have discovered, use the `{}` tool at top left of edit box to keep some reasonable formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest `awk` for that, as it is pretty simple with it:

```
lsusb | awk '/ZTE/ {print $6}'
```

The awk command above searches for lines which contain the pattern `ZTE` like this:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 ZTE foo bar
```

and prints the sixth column of that line. (Columns are separated by whitespaces by default)

---

With `sed`:

```
lsusb | sed -n '/ZTE/ s/.*ID \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

The sed command applies to lines in lsusb's output which contain the string `ZTE`. Like this:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 ZTE foo bar
```

The `s/` substitute command matches all non whitespace characters after `ID:<space>` and replaces the whole line with just the id, and then prints the line. (The `-n` command line option tells `sed` that it should not print lines by default)